# If $|z|<\frac{1}{2}$ then $|(1+i)z^{3}+iz|<\frac{3}{4}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Prove that $z\in \Bbb C$: $|z|<\frac{1}{2}$ then $|(1+i)z^{3}+iz|<\frac{3}{4}$

I tried:$|(1+i)z^{3}+iz|=|z||(1+i)z^{2}+i|<\frac{1}{2}|(1+i)z^{2}+i|$ and I don't know what to do afterwards.

Help me please, I can't prove that.

Comment: Itried:$|(1+i)z^{3}+iz|=|z||(1+i)z^{2}+i|<\frac{1}{2}|(1+i)z^{2}+i|$ and i dont know what to do afterwards :<

Comment: include what you tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p(z)=(i+1)z^3+iz$ is a polynomial, hence a holomorphic function, hence it attains its maximum modulus over the closed region $|z|\leq\frac{1}{2}$ on the boundary $|z|=\frac{1}{2}$. That gives:

$$|p(z)|=\left|iz\right|\cdot\left|(1-i)z^2+1\right|\leq \frac{1}{2}\left(1+\left|(1-i)z^2\right|\right)\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\right).$$

Comment: And that is as tight a bound as one can ever get!  +1 And good to see you back Jack!  Where have you been hiding?  - Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV: nice to meet you again. I wasn't hiding, I just was kind of busy with my new work, I am teaching math in a Italian high school for now :)

Comment: Congratulations on your new position.  And I didn't really think you were hiding; I suspected you might be busy with your dissertation research.  - Mark

Answer (score 2):

$$|(1+i)z^3+iz|< |(1+i)z^3|+|iz|=\sqrt{2}\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2} <2\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{4}$$
How's this?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that we were unaware of the Maximum Modulus Theorem and wished to find the maximum of the function $f(z)=|(1+i)z^3+iz|$ subject to the constraint that $|z|<1/2$.  Then, we could proceed by writing

$$\begin{align}
f(z)&=|(1+i)z^3+iz|\\\\
&=|z|\,\left|1+2^{1/2}|z|^2e^{i(2\arg(z)-\pi/4)}\right|
\end{align}$$

Obviously, for any value of $|z|$, the maximum of $f$ occurs when $2\arg (z)-\pi/4=0$.  And therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
\sup_{|z|<1/2}f(z)&=\sup_{|z|<1/2}\left(|z|\,|1+2^{1/2}|z|^2\right)\\\\
&=\frac12\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\right)\\\\
&<\frac34
\end{align}$$

And we are done!